# get dataurl of canvas after each new drawing in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, data-url

I'm trying to loop trough a certain list and always redraw my canvas. After redrawing the canvas I'm trying to receive the dataurl of the canvas and push it into an array. That part works but it always give me the same dataurl as the first one.

When I look at the drawing in the canvas I always get the correct result, but I can't get the dataurl for that drawing.

```
var planNo = 0;
var map_json = {};

function getCanvasImages() {
    var coordinates = {};

    var plans = $.getJSON(site_url + 'DesktopModules/DNN.WebAPI/API/Ajax/GetPlanProjectsByProjectNo?projectNo=P0104');
    var lots= $.get(site_url + 'DesktopModules/DNN.WebAPI/API/Ajax/GetTranslatedByProjectNo?projectNo=P0104');

    $.when(plans, lots).done(function (p, l) {
        if (p != null && p != undefined) {
            var imagePositionY = 10;
            var table = $('table.livingTable');         

            $.each(p[0], function (key, value) {
                var canvas = map_shape[0]; // or document.getElementById('canvas');
                canvas.width = canvas.width;

                planNo = p[0][key].PlanNo;
                map_json = p[0][key].Coordinates;

                if (map_json != null) {
                    if (map_json.image != undefined) {
                        if (map_json.image.shift_x == undefined) map_json.image.shift_x = 0;
                        if (map_json.image.shift_y == undefined) map_json.image.shift_y = 0;
                        if (map_json.image.scale == undefined) map_json.image.scale = 1;

                        if (map_json.image.filename != undefined) {
                            loadImage();
                        }
                    }

                    if (map_json.shapes == undefined) {
                        map_json.shapes = [];
                    }
                }
            });                
        }
    });
};

var dataUrls = [];

function loadImage() {
    //console.log(map_json);
    map_bg_img.onload = function () {
        updateBackground();
        updateIcons();
        canvas.fadeIn("fast");
    }
    map_bg_img.src = (map_json.image.filename.indexOf("http") > -1 ? map_json.image.filename : map_json.image.filename);
    dataUrls.push(canvas[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Put the .push() inside your onload:

```
dataUrls.push(canvas[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
```

Remember that `map_bg_img.src` is asynchronous so it will start working and immediately release to the next line in your code--so your looping is going faster than you expect.

Comment: I've already tried that but then nothing is pushed into my array. I get an empty dataurl then

Comment: It should work according to this  http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/